# Poor disk performance on KVM guest

Tags: kvm-virtualization, lvm, proxmox, luks, mdraid

I have a server running Proxmox and some Linux VMs running on it.

- On the host, I get 200+ MB/s write to the disk
- On a VM, I only get around 50-60 MB/s

Caching is disabled for all VMs. 
I'm using Virtio-SCSI as storage controller

Specs of the server:

```
SuperMicro 5018R-WR
Intel Xeon E5-2620v4
64GB memory
4x 1TB WD RE (WDC WD1003FBYZ-010FB0)
Software RAID 10 + dmcrypt + lvm(thin)
```

I know that mdraid is not supported by proxmox, but as I get the full speed on the host, I don't think that's the problem.

Any hints would be very appreciated.

Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: Are you using paravirtualized disks/controllers?

Comment: What disk image format are you using? Can you show the output of `qemu-img info <imagefile>` (with the guest powered off)? Can you try enabling writeback caching on the guest disk?

Comment: I'm using LVM-Thin for VMs. I have read that the recommendation is to use no cache, but I will try writeback and come back with a feedback.

Comment: ~190 MB/s with writeback cache. Why is the difference to none so big? And how about safety of writeback in case of a power outage?

Comment: This is why God invented the UPS.

Comment: That's why the server is colocated in a professional datacenter with 2 power feeds & UPS, but there's still a minimal risk :-)

Comment: Another question, why is writing without cache so slow? On a RAID 10 with 4 WD Gold I'd expect ~200MB/s without any caching. Also the FSYNC rate is very low (40-50/s). Probably related with the encryption layer?